# How can I resolve SSL Mixed Content issue caused by Gravatar?

Tags: ssl, mixed-content

Gravatar is causing mixed content issue especially when a user is logged in. For logged out users, there is no issue. My site loses the green Security (SSL) padlock on the browser. For all the pages which logged in Users visit, there is Mixed content. The message on display by Chrome/Firefox usually
that the page was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure image 'http://gravatar.com/avatar/b87daeb6292d165f7bd8db0dbb2e0a8b?s=400&d=identicon'. This content should also be served over HTTPS.

Is there any way to resolve this pls?

Answer (score 0):

This does not happen with my blog. Check out the attached image for more information.

[image: Mixed Content Error]

Yes, I faced this error two month back but I resolved it using cloudflare. I made the following two changes to load all the resources including image on https.

1. In Crypto Page of Cloudflare, changed the setting to always HTTPS and Automatic Redirect.
2. Made similar change in Cloudflare plugin active in WordPress.

You will find the detailed step by step tutorial on acheving this at below article
[How to Fixed Mixed Content Error in WordPress?](https://loveumarketing.com/fix-mixed-content-issue-website/)